# Keras LSTM training accuracy stuck at low levels for NLP task

Tags: keras, lstm

I am using  an LSTM architecture to create a chatbot. I am using GloVe embedding.
During my training process, my Training accuracy gets stuck at very low values (0.1969) and no progress happens. I am attaching my code below. Can you tell me what can be done to improve the training?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Flatten, Dense, LSTM
from keras.optimizers import Adam


model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words,embedding_dim,input_length=maxlen))
model.add(LSTM(units=100,return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer="glorot_normal", recurrent_initializer="glorot_normal", activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(LSTM(units=100,return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer="glorot_normal", recurrent_initializer="glorot_normal", activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(LSTM(units=100,return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer="glorot_normal", recurrent_initializer="glorot_normal", activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(LSTM(units=100,return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer="glorot_normal", recurrent_initializer="glorot_normal", activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.layers[0].set_weights([embedding_matrix])
model.layers[0].trainable = False

model.compile(loss='cosine_proximity', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
epochs = 500,
batch_size = 32,
validation_data=(x_val,y_val))

Epoch 498/500
60/60 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: -0.1303 - acc: 0.1969 - val_loss: -0.1785 - val_acc: 0.2909
Epoch 499/500
60/60 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: -0.1303 - acc: 0.1969 - val_loss: -0.1785 - val_acc: 0.2909
Epoch 500/500
60/60 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: -0.1303 - acc: 0.1969 - val_loss: -0.1785 - val_acc: 0.2909
```

Further training (on the same conversation data set ) does not improve accuracy.

Comment: To understand the problem you are trying to model and the formulation of your solution: apparently, `x_train` is a list of sentences encoded as word indices. But what is the `y_train`? What are the shapes of `x_train` and `y_train`, i.e. `x_train.shape` and `y_train.shape`?

Comment: y_train (and y_val) is a list of word_embedding vectors that has been extracted from the Glove embedding matrix. 
x_train.shape 
(118, 16)
y_train.shape 
(118, 16, 100)

Answer (score 1):

Add BatchNormalization layer after Embedding and LSTM too. This helps in regularizing the learning. I added it and it helped me. Also, look at data. There might be some issue too.

```
#clear session
keras.backend.clear_session()
model = Sequential()
#embedding layer
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=pad_length))

#Batch Norm layer
model.add(BatchNormalization())

#First LSTM layer
model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))

#Batch Norm layer
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#add dropout too
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

#Second LSTM layer
model.add(LSTM(units=100))

#Batch Norm
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```